# Why are my renders being rendered by my CPU and not my GPU?

Tags: rendering, gpu

In this screencap you can see I have GPU Compute selected but my rendering is being done by my CPU.  Does the fact that GPU Compute is grayed out mean GPU acceleration isn't available on my card (GeForce GTX1080, supposedly supported by Blender), or are there other configuration issues?  Thanks for any tips.
[image]

Comment: Yes you are right the GPU is grey means it is not used or supported with your system .I have also this GPU grey

Answer (score 1):

You are enabling **Open Shading Language**.

Currently it's only support by CPU instruction.

Disable it first.

---

Please check your preference setting,

[image]

Check only GTX 1080 for CUDA device, save the preference and you might need to restart your Blender (most of the time don't need).

Comment: I only have GTX 1080 checked under CUDA.  However, under OpenCL it says, "No compatible GPUs found for path tracing.  Cycles will render on the CPU."  Maybe that's the problem.  If so, what's the solution?

Comment: Wait? Why OpenCL? Nvidia should go with CUDA selected. OpenCL is for AMD card

Comment: Although they look likes tabs, but those are actually toggle options. Cycles will use the active(blue) one  for rendering.

Comment: Aah, I must have left OpenCL set after checking all the settings.  If I set it back to CUDA things go a lot faster.  However, while CPU usage drops to around 25%, GPU usage only climbs to about the same amount.  Why doesn't it climb more?  Thanks for getting me this far.

Comment: rendering tile size issue,

Comment: > rendering tile size issue
Not sure what this means.  In any event, it turns out that Windows Task Manager doesn't accurately report GPU usage; you need a third-party app for that.  Using the free GPU-Z I can see that the GPU is, in fact, maxed out.

Comment: You can change type of the four chart of the GPU panel in task manager, change one of them to CUDA and you might see a full usage CUDA compute

Comment: Aah, yes.  That works, too.  Thanks!